# Time Complexity of my program in competitive programming question City Plan

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, time-complexity

**F. City Plan**

time limit per test: 2 seconds

memory limit per test: 256 megabytes

input: standard input

output: standard output

**Problem Description:**
There are  houses in one particular city that were built along one straight road. For simplicity, we can say that the -th house is located at integer point  (0≤≤10^9, all  are distinct).

You are participating in one project, and you were asked to calculate for each house  the distance  from the -th house to the farthest other house.

Let's say that the distance between the houses  and  is equal to |−|, where || is the absolute value of . Then  can be calculated as max1≤≤(|−|).

Spending some time, you finally calculated all  values 1,2,…,. But, at the same time, you've lost a piece of paper containing a list of all house positions .

You are too lazy to measure all house positions, and you believe that actual house positions are not so important for the project. So the question is: can you create an array 1,2,…, that is consistent with the array  you've calculated?

**Input:**
The first line contains a single integer  (1≤≤10^4) — the number of test cases. Next  cases follow.

The first line of each test case contains the single integer  (2≤≤2⋅10^5) — the number of houses in the city.

The second line of each test case contains  integers 1,2,…, (1≤≤10^7), where  is the maximum distance from house  to some other house.

**Additional constraints on the input:**

- The array  is correct, i. e. there exists at least one array  that is consistent with array .
- The total sum of  among all test cases doesn't exceed 2⋅105.

**Output:**
For each test case, print  integers 1,2,…, (0≤≤10^9) — the positions of houses that produce the given array . All  must be distinct.

If there are several solutions, print any. Note that the order of  matters since it affects the value of .

I wrote a solution that runs in `O(n)` time but I am still getting TLE.
Maybe there something wrong I might be doing?? I am confused

Here is my soution

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void solve() {
    int n, maximum = -1;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n, 0);

    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> a[i];
        maximum = max(a[i], maximum);
    }

    vector<bool> mark(maximum + 1, 0);
    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (mark[maximum - a[i]])
            cout << 0 + a[i] << " ";
        else {
            cout << maximum - a[i] << " ";
            mark[maximum - a[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    cout << '\n';
    return;
}   
int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
        solve(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` [loads the gun](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/4581301) and `using namespace std;` [takes the safety off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/4581301). It is now really easy to shoot yourself in the foot. Use only with great caution.

Comment: Perhaps there is a O(log(N)) or O(1) solution you have yet to consider.

Comment: Note: `vector<bool>` is an odd duck. It's weird enough that [it gets its own documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). It's really cool in that it compresses the bools down to bits, but that means the program has to spend time compressing, decompressing, and making proxy objects. If you have enough memory, use a `vector<uint8_t>`. It's 8 times the size, but noticeably faster in many cases.

Comment: Since the highest length of input per test is 2 * 10^5 and I heard cpp can run 4*10^8 operations per second.
Given time per test is 2 seconds The solution should more than enough ??

Comment: I tried the same with array too btw still does the same.

Comment: C++ will use everything it can get, but if you compile for and run the program on a [Dorito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6510) 4*10^8 is optimistic.

Comment: @user4581301 are you hinting me there is an actual solution with that complexity or are you just guessing ??

Comment: @Alpha々Reaper *The solution should more than enough ??* -- Wherever you got this question from, does the site have solutions already written where you can look at them?  If they are also O(n), then I suggest you not waste any further time and try another question (or better yet, forget it and learn C++ properly using proper materials, not competitive coding websites).

Comment: Haven't even looked at improved algorithms, but the two typical causes of TLE are Algorithm is too slow and bug in the code. I've been focusing on bug in the code.

Comment: If you could could post me the solution I've been trying for more than 2.5hrs on this one.
Any high level solution or hint would also be helpful.

Comment: Wow, only 2.5hrs!  I've spent weeks on debugging single issues.  I wish all of my issues were resolved in 2.5 hrs or less.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik -- The competitive site where this question comes from is, by the looks of it, one of the worst ones out there (granted they are all bad, as they do not teach C++).  With that site, unless you know about that `sync_with_stdio` and all the irrelevant things associated with I/O, all of the effort in trying to code a solution goes down the drain.

Comment: That said, this question is very nearly the Cadillac of Competition questions. Clear question, well laid out, and full code of reasonable length.

Comment: My two cents are, don't initiallize the vector to 0 because they will be filled on the next line, you are wasting time with the zero initialization, secondly if houses are in order then you don't need to store the houses in the vector to begin with, the max is already the first input, the rest you can figure out as the input is being read, you only need to keep track of the max and the last input read.

Comment: @user4581301 full code of reasonable length, cadillac of questions ??
The code is good ? 
Is there something I am missing

Comment: @Alpha々Reaper most competition TLE questions are utter crap, downvoted into the deepdark and deleted within minutes. This is a legit question. It has everything it needs to be answered. Kinda surprised no one's taken the time to give it a decent answer yet, but the competition questions often don't get answers. That would kinda defeat the point of the competition.

Comment: The question is from a practice round though.

Comment: I've submitted the successful solution. I don't know why I asked chatgpt about my problem anyway  it said bool array of long length might be the problem. It suggested unordered_set instead of bool array. I tried the same logic with `unordered_set`  now solution ran in `109ms` instead of getting a timeout at `2000ms`.

Comment: Don't know what might be the underlying cause ??

Comment: You'd have to ask a new question about that. Unless there were other changes to the code I wouldn't expect a set to speed things up. It doesn't get much faster than array look-up.

Comment: @Alpha々Reaper There is no way a bool array is 20 times slower than an unordered_set, and this should have raised your suspicions about such a site you are working with *if the code is essentially the same*.  The *only* way this is possible is if you are doing a linear search in the bool array, while the unordered_set, you are just doing a `find()`, since an unordered_set is basically a hash table (which changes the data structure used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

void solve() {
    int n, maximum = -1;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];

    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> a[i];
        maximum = max(a[i], maximum);
    }

    //bool mark[maximum+1];
    // for (int i=0; i < maximum+1; ++i) 
    //  mark[i] = 0;

    unordered_set<int> mark;
    
    // vector<bool> mark(maximum + 1, 0);
    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (mark.count(maximum - a[i]))
            cout << a[i] << " ";
        else {
            cout << maximum - a[i] << " ";
            mark.insert(maximum - a[i]);
        }
    }
    cout << '\n';
    return;
}
    
int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
        solve(); 
    return 0;
}
```

I used this for submission.

When I used bool array(commented in the code) It causes a segmentation fault for the test

```
1
2
10000000 10000000
```

When I used `vector<bool>`(commented in the code) the code works as expected but causes TLE at 2000ms.

When I used `unordered_set<int>`(used in the code) the submission was successful and ran under 109 ms.

The only change in the code was the declaration of `mark` as bool[], vector and unordered_set and this code below

for `bool[]` and `vector<bool>` I used

```
for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (mark[maximum - a[i]])
        cout << 0 + a[i] << " ";
    else {
        cout << maximum - a[i] << " ";
        mark[maximum - a[i]] = 1;
    }
}
```

I was still directly accessing indices after calculating `maximum - a[i]`.

I knew vector was slow but couldn't figure out why `bool[]` was getting a segmentation fault.

I was sure it would work because I used the exact same logic for the `bool[]` and the `vector<bool>`. **Not a single change**.